# Is there any way to reduce duplication in these two linq queries

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Building a bunch of reports, have to do the same thing over and over with different fields

```
    public List<ReportSummary> ListProducer()
    {
        return (from p in Context.stdReports                    
                group p by new { p.txt_company, p.int_agencyId }
                    into g
                    select new ReportSummary
                    {
                        PKi = g.Key.int_agencyId,
                        Name = g.Key.txt_company,
                        Sum = g.Sum(foo => foo.lng_premium),
                        Count = g.Count()
                    }).OrderBy(q => q.Name).ToList();
    }

    public List<ReportSummary> ListCarrier()
    {
        return (from p in Context.stdReports
                group p by new { p.txt_carrier, p.int_carrierId }
                    into g
                    select new ReportSummary
                    {
                        PKi = g.Key.int_carrierId,
                        Name = g.Key.txt_carrier,
                        Sum = g.Sum(foo => foo.lng_premium),
                        Count = g.Count()
                    }).OrderBy(q => q.Name).ToList();
    }
```

My Mind is drawing a blank on how i might be able to bring these two together.

Comment: If you use the extension methods(dot notation) instead of the sql like query notation, both your queries will look the same except for the lambda you pass into group by. With a cursory look I'm guessing just the `Func<KeySource,TKey> keySelector` changes, see [IEnumerable.GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx) on msdn.  So you would have a `Func<KeySource,TKey> myKeySelector` and the rest is common code. Wonder if I'm making enough sense, its waay to late and night and I'm on a new OSX so I can't write any C# right now.

Comment: You can use Expression tree to build dynamic queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all that changes between the two queries is the group key, parameterize it.  Since it's a composite key (has more than one value within), you'll need to create a simple class which can hold those values (with generic names).

In this case, to parameterize it, make the key selector a parameter to your function.  It would have to be an expression and the method syntax to get this to work.  You could then generalize it into a function:

```
public class GroupKey
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

private IQueryable<ReportSummary> GetReport(
    Expression<Func<stdReport, GroupKey>> groupKeySelector)
{
    return Context.stdReports
        .GroupBy(groupKeySelector)
        .Select(g => new ReportSummary
        {
            PKi = g.Key.Id,
            Name = g.Key.Name,
            Sum = g.Sum(report => report.lng_premium),
            Count = g.Count(),
        })
        .OrderBy(summary => summary.Name);
}
```

Then just make use of this function in your queries using the appropriate key selectors.

```
public List<ReportSummary> ListProducer()
{
    return GetReport(r =>
        new GroupKey
        {
            Id = r.int_agencyId,
            Name = r.txt_company,
        })
        .ToList();
}

public List<ReportSummary> ListCarrier()
{
    return GetReport(r =>
        new GroupKey
        {
            Id = r.int_carrierId,
            Name = r.txt_carrier,
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

I don't know what types you have mapped for your entities so I made some assumptions.  Use whatever is appropriate in your case.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the only thing that changes are the names of the grouping parameters. Could you write a wrapper function that accepts lambdas specifying the grouping parameters? Or even a wrapper function that accepts two strings and then builds raw T-SQL, instead of using LINQ?

Or, and I don't know if this would compile, can you alias the fields in the group statement so that the grouping construct can always be referenced the same way, such as `g.Key.id1` and `g.Key.id2`? You could then pass the grouping construct into the `ReportSummary` constructor and do the left-hand/right-hand assignment in one place. (You'd need to pass it as dynamic though, since its an anonymous object at the call site)

Comment: The anonymous type in the `Select` varies too.

Comment: Only in how it refers to the grouping object. The structure of the object is the same in both cases, so I think it could be generalized (kind of like itsme86's answer)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
public List<ReportSummary> GetList(Func<Record, Tuple<string, int>> fieldSelector)
{
    return (from p in Context.stdReports                    
        group p by fieldSelector(p)
            into g
            select new ReportSummary
            {
                PKi = g.Key.Item2
                Name = g.Key.Item1,
                Sum = g.Sum(foo => foo.lng_premium),
                Count = g.Count()
            }).OrderBy(q => q.Name).ToList();
}
```

And then you could call it like this:

```
var summary = GetList(rec => Tuple.Create(rec.txt_company, rec.int_agencyId));
```

or:

```
var summary = GetList(rec => Tuple.Create(rec.txt_carrier, rec.int_carrierId));
```

Of course, you'll want to replace `Record` with whatever type `Context.stdReports` is actually returning.

I haven't checked to see if that will compile, but you get the idea.

Comment: Note that because this is likely a query provider and not LINQ to Objects you'll want to pass in an `Expression<Func<Record, Tuple<string, int>>` instead of the actual function which will let you use the `IQueryable` overload.